# Conda: created env becomes base upon activating, and base env loses its name - how to fix?

Tags: batch-file, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Ok so this is what I want - a batch script that starts base conda and activates a created environment, like so:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
cd C:\
call conda activate default
cmd /k
```

This works and I end up in my created env, however, upon listing environments, I get the following:

```
(default) C:\>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                         C:\Program Files\miniconda3
base                  *  C:\Users\ROKKRB\.conda\envs\default
```

That is, my default (created) env becomes base, and base loses its name and I can't access it anymore.

What is happening and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you should use ```CD /D C:\```. Next, what is the purpose of using `cmd /k`? I ask because that is starting another instance of `cmd.exe` and keeping it open for another command. That particular instance is not the one with your acivated environment.

Comment: Have you installed `conda` in the environment? The `conda` package should never be installed anywhere other than **base**.

Comment: @Compo adding /d results in "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." Either way, cd C:\ does the job and it's beside the point. As for /k, agreed, it's not needed. I thought that without it the cmd prompt would auto close.

Comment: @merv I did not install it, I just updated it in the newly created environment. That means, it comes pre-installed along with the creation of the environment. The reason I can't use base for anything really is because I don't have write permissions in sys folders - corporate policy etc.

Comment: Okay. Having `conda` installed entails the reported behavior - such environments self-report as "**base**" while activated. Quick fix might be `conda deactivate && conda activate` or by specifying path, i.e., `conda activate C:\Program Files\miniconda3`.

Comment: @merv that explains it. No quick fix seems to be working though - whichever environment is active, it self-reports as base. Will have to work around it. Thanks!

Comment: @RokasKarabevičius, ```CD /D C:\``` is the 100% correct command. If it is outputting the message you have commented, then I would be very confident that the directory name is incorrect! You also appear to have completely missed the point I was making about your last line, the `/k` was not the problem, `cmd /k` is. I would advise that you begin with `cd /?` and `cmd /?` and read the output.

Comment: @Compo I've tried it again and can confirm ``CD /D C:\`` works, and it may be the correct command, however it doesn't change the outcome in this case. As for `cmd` - if I remove it, the terminal window terminates. I need it open, and leaving `cmd` in the script keeps it open. Thanks

Comment: It does keep the window open, but only a window inside the original window. Type `exit` into it, then press the `[ENTER]` key, and see what happens.